# Combine parallel branches into linear git history

Tags: git

have a repository with multiple roots looking like this where J is the merge commit

```
A---C-D-E-----H-I-J
  B-------F-G----/
```

I want it to look like this

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J
```

B needs to go between A and C because the commit date is between A and C, so the resulting linear history needs to be combined based on the date, I do not just want the one rebased on top of the other.

The files in the 2 branches are in different subdirectories and can therefore not create conflicts.

Obviously the above is just an example. The real repo contains multiple parallel branches and many commits, so a manually rebasing part by part is out of the question.

Comment: Why is this needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it is date based, you can order commits with `git rev-list` and cherry-pick them then:

```
git rev-list --date-order --reverse J ^A | xargs git cherry-pick
```

Comment: Right, though you need `--reverse` here since the default is newest-first.